# How to get type and number of .zip contents

Tags: c#, compression, gzipstream

How can i get the content names of a zipped folder in C# i.e. name of files and folders inside the compressed folder? 
I want to decompress the zip by using GZipStream only.

thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) only. You will need an implementation of the ZIP standard such as [#ziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/). Quote from MSDN:

> Compressed GZipStream objects written
>   to a file with an extension of .gz can
>   be decompressed using many common
>   compression tools; however, this class
>   does not inherently provide
>   functionality for adding files to or
>   extracting files from .zip archives.

Example with #ziplib:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("test.zip"))
using (var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(stream))
{
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        // entry.IsDirectory, entry.IsFile, ...
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how?